# How to update the value in action creator - react

Tags: reactjs, redux

i am trying to update my response in the action creator.

Once then i receive response i am updating the time zone(as of now hardcoded)

Here the response

```
 data = [
 {
   "created": {timestamp: "2018-05-12T16:55:32Z", Id: "234j", name: "jim"}
    "id": "804690986026920900000061579629"
    "lastUpdated": {timestamp: "2018-05-12T16:55:32Z", Id: "234j", name: "jim"}
    "note": "standard 9"
 },                             
 {
   "created": {timestamp: "2018-05-12T17:49:32Z", Id: "444a", name: "antony"}
    "id": "804690986026920900000061579630"
    "lastUpdated": {timestamp: "2020-05-12T16:49:32Z", Id: "444a", name: "antony"}
    "note": "standard 9"
 },
 {
   "created": {timestamp: "2018-05-12T17:55:12Z", Id: "123m", name: "mark"}
    "id": "804690986026920900000061579631"
    "lastUpdated": {timestamp: "2020-05-12T17:49:12Z", Id: "123m", name: "mark"}
    "note": "standard 9"
 }
];
```

action.js

```
then((results) => {
  const hardcodedValue =  "2020-05-22T04:49:44Z"
  const getLocaltime = results.data.map((updatetime)=>{
    return {...updatetime, lastUpdated.timestamp:hardcodedValue}
   //getting error at lastUpdated.timestamp
  })
  results.data = getLocaltime;
    dispatch({
      type: "RECEIVED_DATA",
      payload: updateId === '' ? {} : results,
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way, since its new data and the object reference can stay the same, you can just mutate it like this:

```
then((results) => {
  const hardcodedValue = "2020-05-22T04:49:44Z";
  results.data.forEach((row) => {
      row.lastUpdated.timestamp = hardcodedValue;
  });
  dispatch({
    type: "RECEIVED_DATA",
    payload: localAccountId === '' ? {} : results,
  })
```

Comment: Thank you , I have few more queries, Based on time stamp
what i am getting is UTC time need to convert it to local,If you have any idea on that please do share that

Comment: You can simply create a new Date object with new Date("2020-05-22T04:49:44Z"); and if you render that for example with .toString(), it will be local.

Comment: already created.timestamp and lastupdated .timestamp are coming from the sql timestamp(backend Response), so i need to make it to local in the action creator  itself?

Comment: Yes, where ever you receive that data on your client, wrap it with a date object and it will be local. Be careful in sending it back to the server to make sure its utc again.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not a valid object:

```
{ ...updatetime, lastUpdated.timestamp:hardcodedValue }
```

Try fixing it to:

```
{ ...updatetime, lastUpdated: { ...updatetime.lastUpdated, timestamp: hardcodedValue } }
```

You could also do it like this:

```
updatetime.lastUpdated.timestamp = hardcodedValue;
return {...updatetime}
```

This would update the lastUpdated object and since you return a new outer object, the reference would change and you would not lose any data.

Comment: is the only we to update?? results.data = getLocaltime;

Comment: @Domino987 what happes if i do 
{ ...updatetime, lastUpdated: { timestamp: hardcodedValue } }
??

Comment: @user13465472 You will lose the information within the previous lastUpdated object. It would only be {
   "created": {timestamp: "2018-05-12T17:55:12Z", Id: "123m", name: "mark"}
    "id": "804690986026920900000061579631"
    "lastUpdated": {timestamp: "2020-05-12T17:49:12Z",}    "note": "standard 9"
 }

Comment: @Domino987 one more question ?is this the only way we to update response ?? results.data = getLocaltime